# UIStackView subview doesn't get reinstalled

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an `UIStackView` with a subview that is supposed to be uninstalled in *wAny* *hC* and installed in other cases. But what happens is once the subview is uninstalled (if I rotate the device or if it's at *hC* at load) the subview doesn't reappear once the height is no longer compact.

Why doesn't the view show up? There are no warnings in the console or anywhere else. The problem is identical on the simulator and physical device.

If it makes any difference, the stack view is initially `hidden`.

Answer (score 0):

By default all Interfacebuilder properties are weak. When the view is removed from the layout there is no reference to it and the property will be released (set to nil). A strong pointer should solve your problem.

```
weak var myStackView: UIStackView
```

should be changed to

```
var myStackView: UIStackView
```

For reference:

> Because a weak reference does not keep a strong hold on the instance it refers to, it is possible for that instance to be deallocated while the weak reference is still referring to it. Therefore, ARC automatically sets a weak reference to nil when the instance that it refers to is deallocated. Because weak references need to allow nil as their value, they always have an optional type. You can check for the existence of a value in the weak reference, just like any other optional value, and you will never end up with a reference to an invalid instance that no longer exists.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID48

Comment: Unfortunately that's not it. I changed all the weak references (by removing *weak*) to the stack view, its container and the label and there is no effect - the label still fails to reappear.

Comment: Can you access the stack view? E.g print a property?

Comment: Yes, I can (I tried `print("\(stackView.description)")`). But the stack view itself doesn't get uninstalled, one of its subviews gets uninstalled but doesn't get reinstalled. I can access that subview as well.

Comment: But it is still in arranged sub views? If yes, is the frame of the stack view in a visible area?

Comment: Oops, I now understand what that means, I'll check.

Comment: It's not in `arrangedSubviews` when it's not visible, even though it should be installed for that orientation (for any orientation that doesn't have compact height). And the entire stack view should be in visible area in that case because it's much smaller than the height of the screen (when it's not compact height).

Comment: I guess the views in arranged subviews are removed when the view gets uninstalled and won't be added, when the view gets installed. You can add it manually. You can subclass the stack view and the override layout subviews method.

Comment: Thanks, but I solved it by instead having a height=0 layout constraint in compact height. It's a filthy inelegant solution that reflects my programming skills. :) Thanks for the hint about `arrangedSubviews`.